# Can I embed a postcode search on my website with Google My Map?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I am hoping that somebody may be able to point me in the right direction with this.

I have a section on this WordPress website I am working on, that displays their Google map, with areas drawn into it displaying the locations where they deliver deliver:

https://www.primalraw.co.uk/freezer-delivery-info/

I have done this by embedding our Google My Map into the page so that customers can click on the "view larger map" and search directly for their post code.

The problem is that a lot of customers do not understand this and I am trying to think of a way to make it simpler, ideally a box on this page where a customer can enter their postcode so once they hit submit it takes them straight to google "search this map" section.

I have done some preliminary searching on Google and looked into a few paid service, but I can't seem to find anything that links with the Google My Map

Thank you in advance for any help you can give

Comment: I can't understand what the problem is with adding the input box and button to be used for a search facility.

Comment: Google my maps doesnt support query parameter so you cant pass it. Instead use Google Maps API to create your layers and updating the map if someone types in input field address or zip or w/e. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon